# 'Unable to create the directory' error in laravel (on the server)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a form whereby the user can upload a picture and send it to the server along with the information in the form. Everything was working fine locally but when I uploaded the code to the server I started getting errors. I changed all the codes concerning the path but its still giving me some errors but a least I can now retrieve pictures.

So now unto the problem. When I submit the form it gives me a "Unable to create the "http://xxx.xx.xx/profileLogo" directory". This is when I'm trying to save the picture into a folder.

Here is the code where I believe the issue is coming from:

`$path = $request->file('logo')->move(
               asset("/profileLogo/"), $fileNameToStore
            );`

Here is the entire code for the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use DB;
use File;

class CompanyProfileController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $result= DB::table('tblcompany')->get();
    if($result==null)
    {
        DB::table('tblcompany')->insert([
            'companyName' =>' ']
     );
    }
    $pic = DB::table('tblcompany')->select('logoName')->limit(1)->value('logoName');
    if($pic==null)
    {
        DB::table('tblcompany')->update(['logoName' => 'noimage.png',]);
    }
    $data['getAllDetails']= DB::table('tblcompany')->get();

    return view('companyProfile.companyProfile', $data);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request)
{
//dd(asset(''));
    $this->validate($request, [
        'companyname' =>'required',
        'shortCode' =>'required',
        'telnum' =>'required',
        'emailid' =>'required',
        'address' =>'required',

    ]);

    //$file_path =  asset('') . '/profileLogo/';
    //$file_path =  asset("/profileLogo/");

    if($request->hasFIle('logo')){
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extention = $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extention;
       $pic = DB::table('tblcompany')->select('logoName')->limit(1)->value('logoName');
       if($pic!='noimage.png')
       {

            //$deletePicPath = $file_path . $pic;
            //die($deletePicPath);
            //File::delete($deletePicPath );
       }



        $path = $request->file('logo')->move(
           asset("/profileLogo/"), $fileNameToStore
        );

        DB::table('tblcompany')->update(['logoPath' => $path,'logoName' => $fileNameToStore,]);

    }


    $companyname= trim($request['companyname']);
    $shortCode= trim($request['shortCode']);
    $telnum= trim($request['telnum']);
    $emailid= trim($request['emailid']);
    $address= trim($request['address']);

    DB::table('tblcompany')->update(
            ['companyName' => $companyname,
            'shortCode' => $shortCode,
            'phoneNo' => $telnum,
            'emailAddress' => $emailid,
            'contactAddress' => $address,]
        );

        return redirect('/company-profile')->with('message','Form Updated');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

So how can I successfully go to the folder and store the picture?

Comment: have u set chmod 775 to public folder

Comment: run `ls -la` on your site dir to check file permissions and file owners

Comment: @Jigs1212 also, don't recommend `777` - recommend `775`

Comment: ok updated  my comment

Comment: Hey guys I'm new to all this. I don't know how to do this

Comment: `asset("/profileLogo/")` creates a _URL_, whereas you want to use a _file system_ path here.

Comment: ok so how to I use a file system path?

Answer (score 4):

Change permissions to folder where you want to save file. For linux:

```
chmod a+rwx folder_name -R
```

It will change permission for folder_name and all folders that are included.
You must do that as a system root.

For windows:

```
C:\>icacls "D:\path_to_folder" /grant John:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are linux, you can log into the server and navigate to the folder you want to have your uploads folder in and create the uploads folder using

```
mkdir uploads
```

After that, give the uploads folder the read and write permission like below

```
sudo chmod -R 777 [path-to-your-uploads-folder]
```

That's what I did and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

You need to give full access to that directory before performing any read write operation. To give permission you can write following command in your linux console.

```
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /path_to_folder
```

In your case

```
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /var/www/html/laravel/assets/profileLogo
```

Make sure you give the correct path of the folder as this is only example.

Comment: you don't need full permissions - set to `775` not `777` :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to do this

Comment: Do you have access to server with ssh? Or are you using cPanel?